# Big O Sum should be accounted?

Tags: sum, big-o, notation

I have an algorithm that the solutions are k sum of things there is a formula to show that? Or is simply the biggest one?

O(k^n + k^(n-1) + k^(n-2) ... + k^0) is O(k^n) or there is a way of representing this?

Thanks is advance

Comment: Writing O(k^n) is enough. O(k^n+...) is basically the same thing, so there's no need to write more symbols.

Comment: This is a *geometric series*: `k^n + k^(n-1) + ... + k^1 + k^0 = [k^(n+1) - 1]/[k - 1] = O(k^(n+1)) = O(k^n)`, since `k` is just a constant. For the same reason, `k^(n-1)` is not technically "smaller" than `k^n` (in an asymptotic sense), since they only differ by a constant factor; so without the prior knowledge that this is a geometric series, it may be dangerous to discard such terms.